# sonar-scanner-cli-4.2 does not find jre/bin/java

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying to run the `sonnarqube` scanner on a docker container on jenkins. I use following image:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
```

I install `java` from here:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

I install `sonnarqube scanner` from here:

```
RUN wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873.zip
```

When running the scanner, I get following error:

```
22:33:55 sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873-linux/bin/sonar-scanner: exec: line 64: /e2e/sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873-linux/jre/bin/java: not found
```

I've checked java path:

```
22:33:49 Step 39/44 : RUN which java
22:33:49  ---> Running in 47df6c73c0b7
22:33:50 /usr/bin/java
```

and append it to my `PATH` env variable (sonnarqube executable too):

```
22:50:57 /usr/bin/java/bin:/sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

In the [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/), they say that they provide a JRE for linux distribution.

But if I inspect the sonnarqube folder, I just see:

```
22:50:39 drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Nov 25 21:50 .
22:50:39 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Nov 25 21:50 ..
22:50:39 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Nov 25 21:50 bin
22:50:39 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Nov 25 21:50 conf
22:50:39 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Nov 25 21:50 lib
```

There's no `sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873/jre/java/bin`

Should the `jre` be in the `sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873` folder? is my `PATH` env var wrong? I can't figure out why java is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need exactly alpine, then:

```
export GLIBC_VERSION=2.34-r0
apk --no-cache add binutils curl
curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub
curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk
curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk
curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk
apk add --no-cache glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk # you must be needed to add || true for alpine newer than 3.15
```

in my tests GLIBC_VERSION 2.34-r0 only working. I tried newer, but doesn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**
This answer is now out of date and is now superseded by the answer provided by @Alexey Kolesaev: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76271486/11543023

---

There are issues with openJDK 11+ being installed on alpine. Alpine Linux uses `musl-libc` for its `libc`, where most other flavours of Linux use `glibc`, GNU's C library. Standard Linux software is built on non-Alpine flavours, like ubuntu and centos, thus normally get linked against `glibc` and so cannot be executed successfully with Alpine as `libc` is not linking to the java installation. The only workaround is installing a `glibc` compatibility layer, which is not simple or using an alpine-openjdk11 container (which you may not be able to use as they are not official images, so have issues in maintainability)

Try a debian (ubuntu) or fedora (centos) distribution and see if you can get it working

Comment: Please refer to new updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76271486/11543023 provided by @AlexyKolesaev

Answer (score 0):

Please check java file in the package sonar-scanner-{version}/jre/bin/java
if it has not you must retry to download new sonar-scanner-{version} and recheck it I'm found this problem because when my MACOS open java file it has no permission and can't open you **must set the privacy & security to allow java**

[image]