# What does mean these errors in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, assemble

I'm trying to assemble a Kotlin project using Gradle and I'm getting this kind of errors:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processProDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:ProDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform misnapworkflow_UX2-release.aar to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /gradle/conf/caches/transforms-3/dad12f3b940e882b6d90ca007996f37e/transformed/jetified-misnapworkflow_UX2-release.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

But I don't understand why it is failing.

Comment: Try invalidate and restart.

Comment: what resources do you have under /res/ ?

Comment: @RaviMishra what do you mean with invalidate?

Comment: @Blundell some XML files and images mainly

Comment: @Felipe File-> invalidate caches...

Comment: Perhaps one of your images is of an unsupported type. Delete them all and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the base Docker image I was taking was an Alpine and after changing it the execution was successful. Probably it was missing something.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70155534/11543023 - this will provide you with clarification of one of the types of issues that can occur with alpine containers